# Add scheduled task without specifiying a schedule yet

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Our deployment wants to create a scheduled task (using `SchTasks.exe`) without specifying a schedule yet.

We tried to specify a trigger "run once in the past", however, that is not possible.

How to register a scheduled task with no trigger using the command line?

We are on Win 2008 R2, so no PowerShell ScheduledTask cmdlets available.

Comment: What is it good for? I’d prepare a script to make a valid schedule and run it when I knew the desired time.

Comment: You are already able to manually trigger the task and test the environment.

Comment: You can also test it when you schedule it for example a year from now. Or you can encapsulate the task call into a batch-file and launch it either manually or from the task scheduler.

Comment: We've scheduled it for 2999/1/1 now ... however, that's not a clean solution. We're looking for "the" solution - it is possible using the UI, so...